# Android Bluetooth Connection with External Bluetooth hardware

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, inputstream

Working on an application that receive input from an external Bluetooth device which 
emits random number frequently
Android application is able to connect to the External Bluetooth device,
Always the input stream object available size is 0.
ie: mInputStream.available() returns 0

Using the following code
http://pastebin.com/WzXHnJ34

Note: I am able to exchange data with Andorid to Android Mobile and tablet

Here my "external Bluetooth device" is an Bluetooth hardware.

**UPDATE :**

My External BluetoothDevice is working on **ModBus Protocols**

Comment: Hi. I have same problem when i called mmInputStream.available() returns 0 value.I think Android Bluetooth does not capture ModBus Protocol Data. I am also trying to reading data from external Bluetooth Device means H/W, but i have same problem that you are facing.If you get any solution then let me know please.

Comment: @Lawrance ya definitely i'll post answer if i found any useful solution. bad to my luck yet not found any solution...